# How to intercept response data in an android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I know we can get it via another httprequest sent by httpclient, but it may have some problems with session, https. Can I intercept the response data in android webview. I don't find such apis. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems impossible... Since Android 4.0 webkit uses **native** chromium http module to execute all http/https requests. It does not provide any hooks or callbacks for the Java layer to intercept.

Unless you want to intercept the request *before* it's sent out by webkit, then you can refer to `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer how to get the resource, but I know, you could take the session Cookie from webview, and use it in own http-Requests or Android Download-Manager.

I have an example, what only takes the php-sessionID from Cookie (this is used for logins on the most php-liked sides)

```
 static final private String   phpSessionName             = "PHPSESSID";


/**
 * Loads PHP Session ID from Cookie
 * 
 * @date    22.09.2015
 * @version 1.0
 * @param   url         
 * @return  PHP SessionID or NULL if cookie contains no SessionID
 */
protected String getPHPSessionID(String url)
{
  String id = null;


  CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
  String cookie               = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
  if(cookie != null)
  {
    String[] cookie_parts = cookie.split(";");
    for(int t=0;t < cookie_parts.length;t++)
    { 
        String[] cookieContent = cookie_parts[t].split("=");
        if(phpSessionName.equals(cookieContent[0]))
        {
         id = cookieContent[1];           
          break;
        }
    }
  } 
  else Log.w(TAG, "getPHPSessionID: no cookie found");    

  return id;
}
```

You can use this like:

```
 String phpSession   = getPHPSessionID("http://yourdomain.com");    
 if(phpSession != null) {
   DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet  request = new HttpGet("http://yourdomain.com/stuff-to-load");
   response   = client.execute( request );

   // Your code to load data or headers or response
   request.addHeader("Cookie",phpSessionName+"="+phpSession);
 }
```

If you do not like Httpclient, because its deprecated, you can youse this session cookie in UrlConnection or other Http Clients too, you only have to add the Cookie header.